# Error when importing folder to S3 Bucket `n is undefined`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, undefined

I'm uploading to S3 and I've gotten a strange error that I can't find any hint to online. The error simply is `n is undefined` and I'm not sure what that means. Almost 50% of the files in the folder upload have failed due to this error. Any help?

[image: Screenshot of errors while in AWS console]

Comment: Try doing the same in incognito

Comment: That is, indeed, weird. Did you try restarting your browser, or trying a different browser? I'm also wondering whether it could be related to permissions -- are you able to upload individual files instead of a folder?

Comment: I think it may have to do with empty folders or files, but I'm not sure. I ended up zipping the entire folder and moving that to S3, which worked fine.

Comment: I ran into this when uploading large objects. Turns out my session was timing out. I logged in as my root user, temporarily adjusted the session timeout for the relevant security policy, and things worked from there. Don't forget to revert your session timeout!